# Arithmetic on $[0,\infty]$: is $0 \cdot \infty = 0$ the only reasonable choice?

Tags: real-analysis, number-systems

On page 18 of Rudin's *Real and Complex* analysis he defines $0 \cdot \infty = 0$ and says that "with this definition the commutative, associative, and distributive laws hold in $[0,\infty]$ without any restriction".

What is not clear to me is whether the quoted statement is a justification of the definition or just a consequence. Wouldn't the commutative, associative, and distributive laws also hold if we define $0 \cdot \infty = \infty$?

Comment: Have you tried checking them yourself?

Comment: Note that the "useful proposition" that is given on the next page (namely "If $0 \leq a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \cdots$, $0 \leq b_1 \leq b_2 \leq \cdots, a_n \to a \text{ and } b_n \to b, $ then $a_nb_n \to ab$") only holds if $0 \cdot \infty$ is defined to be $0$.

Comment: We want the integral of the constant function 0 over a space to be 0, even if the space has infinite measure. The integral of a nonzero constant function c over a space of measure m should be cm, so Rudin's convention (0*infty = 0) makes this formula valid if c = 0 too.  This is what convinced me that Rudin's convention is the right one (for integration theory).

Comment: @Qiaochu: I had checked and it seemed to work for $0 \cdot \infty=\infty$. Was asking to see if I was making some silly error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It may seem strange to define $0\cdot\infty=0$.  However, one verifies without difficulty that with this definition the *commutative, associative, and distributive laws hold in $[0,\infty]$ without any restriction*.

The way this is worded leads naturally to your question, as though Rudin were implying that this is the main justification for defining $0\cdot\infty$ in this way.  Rather, I see this as a bonus after making the convention consistent with what happens when integrating the $0$ function or integrating over a space of measure $0$, as KCd's comment indicates.

If you ask yourself what the possibilities are, you can start by supposing that $0\cdot\infty=x$ for some $x\in[0,\infty]$, and apply the distributive law to see that $x=2x$, so that $x=0$ or $x=\infty$.  You can then verify that with either convention the commutative, associative, and distributive laws will hold, so something more is needed to motivate the choice.  Such a choice will always depend on context, and in some cases it won't be a good idea to even define $0\cdot\infty$.  However, I am not aware of a mathematical context in which the convention $0\cdot\infty=\infty$ is useful.