# why( in measure theory ) zero multiply infinite is zero?

Tags: measure-theory

why( in measure theory ) zero multiply infinite is zero?
I think because the area of line in the plane is zero 
then zero multiply infinite is zero,is it true?

Comment: Where **exactly** and with respect to *what* happens that in measure theory??

Comment: That's not always true that $0\times\infty=0$.  It is usually left undefined.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is referring to the definition of the Lebesgue integral of simple functions.

Comment: A *countable* union of measure zero sets has measure zero. But make it an *uncountable* union, and all bets are off.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/878461/39599) is somewhat related. You may find some of the discussion there helpful.

Comment: preserving the linearity of integral might be a reason: $\int 0.fd\lambda=0.\int fd\lambda$

Comment: I recall that Rudin uses the convention that $0\cdot \infty = 0$ with the caveat that it is purely for convenience in stating certain theorems so a special case doesn't have to be made. The extended reals $[-\infty,\infty]$ don't form a field, but many of the laws can almost be extended to them. In short, it's just for convenience, not a cold hard statement of fact

Comment: One of the main reasons is that it does what you would expect (in most cases). For example $\lambda_2 (\Bbb{R} \times \{1\}) = \lambda_1 (\Bbb{R}) \cdot \lambda_1 (\{1\})$ holds with this conventions, where $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1$ are the two-dimensional and one-dimensional Lebesgue measures. The other reason is linearity of the integral, as @drhab noted.