# Why $0\cdot \infty =0$ in measure theory?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15542/arithmetic-on-0-infty-is-0-cdot-infty-0-the-only-reasonable-choice), it's written that in measure theory $$0\cdot \infty =\infty \cdot 0=0.$$

What does it mean ? So, in measure theory, $$\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{x}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty }x\cdot \frac{1}{x}=\infty \cdot 0=0 \ \ ?$$

It sounds a bit weird... Any explanations?

Comment: Measure theory apart, in general an infinity multiplied by zero is considered an indeterminate form. Loosely said, the answer can take on any value, depending where the infinity and zero "are coming from". So the answer certainly (and quite often) is not zero.

Comment: It is true by definition. In order to fit the usages of measure/integration theory it is convenient. There is not really an explanation.

Comment: I suspect that it means *in contexts where the $0$ and $\infty$ refer to measures of spaces* then taking $0 \cdot \infty = \infty \cdot 0 = 0$ is useful. It says nothing about evaluating limits with indeterminate forms.

Comment: Because we want $\int_0^\infty 0\, dx = 0.$

Answer (score 2):

The definition is useful because, for example, it [makes it easier to state the Theorem that $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ is a null set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976329/).

One may think about it intuitively like this (of course, this is not a proof of the Theorem):
$$\lambda^2(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})=\lambda(\mathbb R)\cdot\lambda(\{0\})=\infty\cdot 0=0.$$

However, your limit manipulation doesn't work because the arithmeticity of limits only holds if both denominator and numerator converge to a number in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "$\lim$" in "$0 \cdot \infty$" nor in "$\infty \cdot 0$", so it is odd that you are introducing one.  Further, as written, both "$0$" and "$\infty$" are *quantities*, not secretly limits.  In fact, the two expressions you write are uses of the most elementary form of multiplication: repeated addition.  Thus, if you have a bag containing infinitely many zeroes and add all of them up, you get zero.  Likewise if you have a bag, known to contain only $\infty$s, but upon opening the bag you find zero of them in the bag, the sum of its contents is zero.

The correct analog with limits is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x} \cdot \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} y = 0$.  This is *not* an indeterminate form because the two variables do not appear under the same limit.  What it *is* is arithmetic with a new symbol, $\infty$, so Rudin needs to define how that arithmetic works.